# Using django-custom-user app on github, how can I get the current user that just created email address

Tags: django, django-1.5

I'm using the django-custom-user app on github: https://github.com/recreatic/django-custom-user

I have a signal as defined:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=EmailUser)
def user_saved(sender=None, **kwargs):
    print("Request finished!")
    user = kwargs["instance"]
    if kwargs["created"]:
        blah = Blah(user=get_user_model(), name="None")
        blah.save()
```

Right now I'm getting the error: Cannot assign "": "Blah.user" must be a "EmailUser" instance.
This error makes sense, because in the github description it says to get a specific email address:

```
user = get_user_model().get(email="user@example.com")
```

My question is... given that this is the case, how can I get the user that was just created? It's not like I have the email address of the user that just logged in? I'm doing this through django admin btw. This is synonymous to in views, you can use request.user. But I'm assuming I can't do that now here.

Can someone explain what arguments are in these callbacks in signals? This callback function has an arbitrary name user_saved, but somehow it gets arguments "sender" and "kwargs." Where are they coming from and where can I find the list of arguments for these callbacks?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
blah = Blah(user=get_user_model(), name="None")
```

Just use:

```
blah = Blah(user=kwargs["instance"], name="None")
```

That's because `Blah()` expects an instance, not the class model.

A signal receiver always has `sender` as the first argument, and then a number of variable arguments (that's why the `*kwargs` is required) as explained in the [signals documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/signals/#receiver-functions). The list of `post-save` arguments can be found in the [post-save documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/signals/#post-save).